# JavaScript:Set File Extension according to Files in folder

Tags: javascript

I am New in javascript i am doing image pagination,

```
function ChangeData(img) 
{
     image = document.getElementById('Image');
     var imagePath="Images/"+img+".jpg";
     image.src = imagePath;
}
```

Here in ChangeData(img) i am passing image name and then concatenate that name with Image Extension and then set it to the img src,

here one thing should keep in mind that all images are copy and paste in Images Folder with 
Image name in sequence number like 1,2,3,4.....etc

here i did Concatenation with .jpg only but if some one place images with .PNG, .BMP, .Gif
then its create Problem here So How Can i do .PNG, .BMp, .GIF Can any one Suggest me? Please...

Comment: Your question has nothing in common with title.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. You can't give multiple extensions to the filename. Do you want to try different extensions until it works?

Comment: Use an AJAX service. Send the image name to the server, it can look in the `Images` directory to find the extension, and send it back tothe client. Then the client updates the `src`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You could pass the extension as a variable to the function.
2.Another way is to convert your pictures to be .jpg.
3.(this is the worst way) Since you know the format of each picture, you can write something like this:

```
{
     **var ext=".jpg";
     if(img=="4"){ext=".png"}
     else if ...**
     image = document.getElementById('Image');
     var imagePath="Images/"+img+**ext;**
     image.src = imagePath;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Friend but here i have no idea about the extension i only know about the Name Of image

Comment: Are you not the one saving the images? If you are, try to convert them (best solution). Else you could try all the formats for each image, until you find one name that exists.

Comment: no,, i Directly Copy and Paste all Images into Images Folder,,With Name in Sequence Order Like 1,2,3.. but the extension might be different,,and i dont know how to check format for each Image..